# What is the right way to call in-between actions from inside @ngrs/effect code?

Tags: angular, angularfire2, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Need help to invoke side-effect actions, while my item saving in Firebase.

*vehicle.service.ts:*

```
...

public addVehicle(vehicle: Vehicle, success, error) {
  return this.vehicles$.push(vehicle).then(success).catch(error);
}
```

*vehicle.effects.ts:*

```
    @Effect()
    addVehicle$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(VehicleActions.ADD_VEHICLE)
    // NEED TO CALL: this._statusActions.dataLoading('adding new vehicle...')) 
    .switchMap(action => 
        Observable.fromPromise(
            this._vehicleService.addVehicle(action.payload,
                suc => this._statusActions.dataAdded(action.payload.name),
                err => this._statusActions.dataNotSaved(action.payload.name)
            ) // I WANT TO CALL, NOT RETURN ONE OF THEM
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an intermediate action

```
 @Effect()
    addVehicleStatusChange$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(VehicleActions.ADD_VEHICLE)
    .switchMap(this._statusActions.dataLoading('adding new vehicle...')) 
    // return action type ADD_VEHICLE_START


 @Effect()
    addVehicle$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(VehicleActions.ADD_VEHICLE_START)
    .switchMap(action => 
        Observable.fromPromise(
            this._vehicleService.addVehicle(action.payload,
                // Success return action ADD_VEHICLE_SUCCESS
                // Error return ADD_VEHICLE_ERROR
           ) 
    ))

 @Effect()
    addVehicleStatusChangeSuccess$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(VehicleActions.ADD_VEHICLE_SUCCESS)
     .switchMap(suc => this._statusActions.dataAdded(action.payload.name)),
    // return action type some random action you don't care 

 @Effect()
    addVehicleStatusChangeError$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(VehicleActions.ADD_VEHICLE_ERROR)
     .switchMap( =err => this._statusActions.dataNotSaved(action.payload.name))
    // Return some random action.
```

What I generally do is dispatch PERFORM_ACTION from components. In effects listen to that action and return new action  PERFORM_ACTION_START.

Once the action is done , return action PERFORM_ACTION_DONE.

Inside reducer i have handler for PERFORM_ACTION_DONE only . I have special reducer for status , there I listen to PERFORM_ACTION_START and PERFORM_ACTION_DONE

Comment: Quite compicated approach, from my poin of view, I loocking for something more graceful. I decide to dispatch side-action with _store.dispatch directly from Effect. It took only one extra line. Plus Store injection of course...

Comment: It is very verbose . But this approach helped me a lot . I could automate lot of my code and still could extend any additional side effects needed in special cases. It helped a lot in unit tests. I use store for tracking status too so this worked out well . Glad you got it working :)